# Could not find property 'uninstallDebug' on project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I want to run my custom task "MyTask" to run before uninstall happens. Code for the same is

`uninstallDebug.dependsOn "MyTask"`

When I run this, it fails with an error

`Could not find property 'uninstallDebug' on project`

whereas, I see a gradle task listed in the Gradle window with that name.
What may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
project.afterEvaluate { p ->
    p.tasks.uninstallDebug.doFirst {
        println 'before uninstall'
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your point. But here I want "uninstallDebug" to be a dependancy for "yourTask". Hence I cannot use your answer since the "uninstallDebug" is not my task. Also, `"uninstallDebug".dependsOn yourTask` won't work.

Btw, the link you've shared doesn't work.

Comment: Still I won't be able to start my task from within this code. Also, I tried your code, it doesn't print the line. What I want is to run integration tests completely and generate report. For that I want to use `uninstallDebug.dependsOn runIntegrationTests`

Comment: It prints the line for me right after `:app:uninstallDebug` is displayed in the build output when I invoke the uninstallDebug task.  You might want to be more specific about how you're intending to invoke a task and get the results you want.  You've not said much in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
  // if your MyTask is in the same project
  uninstallDebug.dependsOn "MyTask"
  // if it is else where
  uninstallDebug.dependsOn project("someProject").project("subProject).tasks["MyTask"]
}
```

Comment: I tried `whenReady` which results in *Could not find property 'spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest' on project ':app'*. Code snippet to follow: `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph -> taskGraph. if (taskGraph.hasTask(spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest)) { spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest.finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests" } }`

Answer (score 0):

`uninstallDebug` along with several other tasks, especially those that have flavor or buildType name in their name are created and added to the gradle taskGraph quite late in the configuration step by the android plugin. What that means, as you have discovered is that you may not be able to refer to them by name early in the config step since they do not exist yet.

The way around this as the other answers point out is to wait until the tasks in question are added to the taskgraph. You can use your line `uninstallDebug.dependsOn "MyTask"` in either `gradle.taskgraph.whenRead{}` or `project.afterEvaluate {}`

Comment: I tried `whenReady` which results in *Could not find property 'spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest' on project ':app'*. Code snippet to follow: `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph -> taskGraph. if (taskGraph.hasTask(spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest)) { spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest.finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests" } }`