# Android - How to define dependancy on a gradle task which is generated after taskGraph is created

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, spoon, spoon-gradle-plugin

**UPDATE**

I could get hold of the task at the runtime. But I am not able to finalize another task. The code I used for is:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
if (taskGraph.hasTask(spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest)) {
    for(Task task : project.gradle.taskGraph.allTasks.iterator())
    {
        if(task.name.startsWith("spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest")) {
            println "spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest task found"
            ciIntegrationTests.mustRunAfter task.name
            task.finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests"
        }
    }
}
```

}

But, still the task "ciIntegrationTests" does not get executed when "spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest" fails. (The println line gets printed though.)

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have a [spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/) task which is built at the runtime (when the task graph is generated) depending on my app flavours. e.g. A task "spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest" is generated at run time and is not accessible to me in build.gradle.

I want to add a dependancy on this task so that this task executes even if some other task fails. I tried these approaches:

```
spoon.finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests"
```

which gives me this error

> Could not find method finalizedBy() for arguments [ciIntegrationTests] on com.stanfy.spoon.gradle.SpoonExtension_Decorated@147456b6.

and

```
spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest.finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests"
```

which gives me an error

> Could not find property 'spoonDeltaAndroidDebugTest'

and

```
"spoonDeltaAndroidDebugTest".finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests"
```

which results in

> No signature of method: java.lang.String.finalizedBy() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ciIntegrationTests]

Is there a way we can access a task in *build.gradle* which is generated at runtime.

Comment: Didn't the answers at your other question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596011/could-not-find-property-uninstalldebug-on-project

Comment: @RaGe No. I tried `whenReady` which results in *Could not find property 'spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest' on project ':app'.* Code snippet to follow:

`gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(spoonFreeDebugAndroidTest)) {
        spoonFreeAndroidDebugTest.finalizedBy "ciIntegrationTests"
    }
}`

Comment: @RaGe I have updated the question.

Comment: I missed the "even if task fails" part of your question earlier. You can make gradle continue on failure if you run with the `--continue` flag. See if that helps. Be mindful that that flag will continue past errors in other parts of your buildscript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your task string with tasks["taskName"]

`tasks["spoonDeltaAndroidDebugTest"].finalizedBy tasks["ciIntegrationTests"]`

Reference:
[More About Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)